# Where can I pay for the Extra Bag on the American Airlines Site?

Tags: luggage, online-resources, fees-and-charges, american-airlines

I have booked a Ticket on American Airlines for London-Chicago for a trip in  March 2018, from the British Airways website (So that I would get BA miles on this booking).

American Airlines charges $100 for the second bag, and hence I need to pay this, since I'll be traveling with 2 checked in bags. The British Airways customer care says that I need to pay American Airlines directly for this excess baggage charge.

I went into the 'My Trips' section on the American Airlines, but I couldn't find where to pay this Excess Baggage Charge in Advance.

On the American Airlines Site, where can I pay for the Extra Bag in advance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most US airlines (including American Airlines) do not give any discounts for paying for bags in advance, so there is generally no way to actually do so on their website, and even if there was there would be no benefit to do so.

If you check-in online you will be able to pay for the bag at the time of check-in.  Alternatively you can pay at the airport when actually dropping the bag at the airport

Comment: American Airlines does not offer the option to pay for any sort of bag fees online at all: they can only be paid at the airport.